# Login page looks weird on Safari on iOS 7

Tags: bug, ios, mobile-safari

[image: Login page on Safari iOS 7]

The bottom part is not clickable.

What's up with that?

Comment: The full site is not built to be compatible with mobile browsers, only the mobile version of the site is.

Comment: @animuson: though it is a bit odd viewing the mobile site on an iPad...

Comment: You might need to take mobile Safari out of incognito mode - it often causes problems.